# CakePHP re-baking concerns

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm new to CakePHP. I added some columns to my table abc. Is it possible not to re-bake my model Abc and its corresponding contoller and views? I already made a lot of changes and I think baking it again will overwrite my existing files. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Baking is only needed when you want to generate automatic code. If you have already modified your Models/Controllers/Views and have added new columns in your database, then you will have to edit manually your Models/Controllers/Views to make relevant modifications.

You will probably want to edit Models to add validation rules for the new columns, to edit Views to add new inputs for these columuns. Controllers will probably remain unchanged.